# How to submit form using href with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to submit form using href with javascript ?

i try this code but not work, How can i do that ? thank you.

```
<script>
function submit_fn() {
    $('#fid').submit();
    //alert("OK");
}
</script>

<form id="fid" method="post" action="main.php" ENCTYPE = "multipart/form-data" style=" display: none; ">
    <input type="text" name="test" value="1"/>
</form>

<a href="JavaScript:submit_fn()"> 
Windows
</a>
```

Comment: Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/t2d4adxr/ You need to be a bit more specific. What does "not work" mean? What happens when you click the link? Do you see errors in the browser's error console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript is case sensitive.

Do this instead:

```
<a href="javascript:submit_fn();">Windows</a>
```

Comment: It sure will, as long as nothing else is wrong with your code.  You are using a jquery selector to submit the form, do you have jQuery referenced at all?

Comment: JS is case sensitive but the `javascript:` prefix is *not* JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

For a link in body: `<a id="alink" href="#">Windows</a>`

`<script>
$('#alink').click( submit_fn );
</script>`

Answer (score 0):

You should actually avoid using inline JS entirely, if ever possible. We can give your anchor element an ID:

```
<form id="fid" method="post" action="main.php" ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data" style="display: none;">
    <input type="text" name="test" value="1"/>
</form>
<a href="#" id="form-submit">Windows</a>
```

...and attach a click event handler to it, using jQuery (make sure you have the library loaded):

```
$(function() {
    $('#form-submit').click(function(e) {
        // Prevent default link behavior
        e.preventDefault();

        // Submit form
        $('#fid').submit();
    });
});
```

Otherwise, there is always native JS that you can work with:

```
var btn = document.getElementById("form-submit");
btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.fid.submit();
} , false);
```

Comment: in form i must action to main.php too

Comment: Then just add `main.php` into the action attribute. You modified your code after I have answered.